# Getting files from sub-directory using a string variable as filepath - C++

Tags: c++, file, csv, ifstream

I have a sub directory in my projects main directory called 'data'. In this directory, are some csv files as well as a text file, and the text file contains the names of some csv files that I want to read data from. Using a while loop, I want to get each file name from the text file 'infile', store it into a string 'files', and use this string variable to open each file in the sub directory. I just dont know how I can access the sub directory using this string variable. What I have done in the code below, is move the files that I want to use into my main directory and it works as intended, but I want to achieve the same thing by just accessing the sub directory. Any suggestions?

```
    string files;

    ifstream infile("data\\met_index.txt"); //Open the text file that shows the csv files needed

    if(!infile) //Exits the program and outputs this message if the file is not found
    {

        cout << "File not found.";

        return -1;

    }

    Vector<string> headers; //A vector of type String to hold the headers for each column

    while(getline(infile, files))
    {

        ifstream datafile(files.c_str()); // How do I access sub directory here?
        if(!datafile) //Exits the program and outputs this message if the file is not found
        {

            cout << "File not found.";

            return -1;

        }
        cout << "File: " << files << endl;

}
```

Comment: You specify a relative path for ifstream, e.g. a file name in the same directory. Following this logic, you can also specify subdir/filename, but you should use the forward slash as a separator. std::string filepath = "data/"; filepath += files; std::ifstream datafile(fiepath.c_str()); Was that the question? Btw. you should not use using namespace std, this is considered bad practice!

Comment: `("data\\" + files).c_str()` ? Also you may take look into https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path for better compatibility, that allows properly concatenate pathes.

Comment: Yes, that is how I get the text file in the sub directory, and then i store them in a string 'files'. But how would I use a string to do the same thing? For example, ifstream("data/" + files variable), what would be the right syntax? And yes, I really need to get into the habit of not using namespace std @Wolfgang

Comment: @AskoldIlvento When I try that statement i get the error expected ',' or ';' before '.' token

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++17 and your compiler supports the `filesystem` library, you should use it for better portability.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    const fs::path directory_path = "data";

    std::ifstream infile{directory_path / "met_index.txt"};
    if (!infile){
        std::cerr << "met_index.txt not found!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<fs::path> file_paths{};

    std::string file_input;
    while(std::getline(infile, file_input)) {
        const fs::path file_path = directory_path / file_input;
        if(fs::exists(file_path)) {
            file_paths.push_back(file_path);
        }
    }

    for(const fs::path& file_path : file_paths) {
        std::cout << file_path << '\n';
    }
}
```

Remember you need to give your compiler flags to compile with C++17, and if you're using g++ or clang++ you might need to link filesystem with `-lstdc++fs`.

Also, if you're using your `met_index.txt` file only to store and read the files you have in your `data` directory so you can easily access them, you should look at [directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to get files inside a directory.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you just want to build the file path accordingly.
For example, this could look like this:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::string filepath("data/");
    std::ifstream datafile(filepath.append(line).c_str());
```

As AskoldIlvento already suggested, you should (if possible) use std::filesystem etc. for better compatibility. Or using a library like boost (boost::fileystem).

Comment: When I try this, as well as the above solutuion, I get the same error as described in the comment above. Don't think its anything with my files, because prior to this I had managed to get everything to work successfully when all was in the main directory

Comment: Please ignore the above, I got it working. Thanks for the advice and help

Answer (score 0):

The `ifstream` constructor accepts either a `char *` or a `const std::string &` argument, so you have no reason to use `._str()`. You could simply change your line with:

```
ifstream datafile(std::string("data\\") + files);
    if(!datafile) //Exits the program and outputs this message if the file is not found
    {
```

Comment: When I try this, it outputs the name of the first file and then I get the error 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument, what(): stof '